# "Set as wallpaper" also creates a copy of the image

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, desktop-background

Every time I try to set an image as wallpaper (right-click on Nautilus and "Set as Wallpaper"), I also get a copy of the image in the same directory (like "Image (copy)"). Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

This happens when I choose an image located in my `~/Pictures/Wallpapers/` directory but not when it is located in a mounted directory.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Nautilus seems to be copying the selected image to a "Wallpapers" directory, at least that is the behavior in 15.04. When you select the wallpaper again, does it come up with a duplicate file error saying something about a "Wallpapers" folder?

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the behavior. If I try to set it again, I just get more copies. If I have it in the ~/Pictures, it tries to copy it to the ~/Pictures/Wallpapers. So... we found a bug?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it? Let's say you delete that image, the wallpaper wouldn't change because the backup is still there.

Comment: I don't want my Pictures directory to have mixed photos, so I have manually created a directory with the name "Wallpapers".  So, every time I set a wallpaper from there, I get a copy that I don't need. 

Moreover, the Wallpaper manager shows pictures only from the ~/Pictures directory (no subdirs), that I consider a bad practice, because I would get a bunch of irrelevant pictures there.

I think that Ubuntu should either:
1. copy the wallpaper to a hidden directory
2. or/and allow to select a wallpaper from ~/Pictures/Wallpapers

At least there should be a check for existence before copying!

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bug, rather an unwanted behavior. I agree with the whole "move it to a hidden folder" idea, but the problem will need much more attention before it gets changed. I've looked through all configuration file on my system and can't find anything related to "Wallpapers", or anything like it.

Comment: Then, maybe, any way to hack it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does setting wallpapers work in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/743911/how-does-setting-wallpapers-work-in-ubuntu)

Comment: [Bug 1181601 on Nautilus package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1181601) has been created: _Right click "Set as Wallpaper" creates duplicates of source file_ Feel free to set if that bug affects you too.

Comment: Upstream on Gnome buzzilla is [bug 688812](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688812) ([not in gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues)). It's from 2012, now "it's just a matter of someone writting the code"..

Answer (score 7):

I found that if you open the file and set it as your wallpaper through the Image Viewer, it won't make a copy.

Comment: But how can I avoid creating copies if I set directly from Context Menu not from Image Viewer?